# how to print lines of a file against each other python

Tags: python, loops, file, iteration

This might be very easy but I have not been able to solve this yet. I have a normal file as below:

```
>seq1
AAAAAAAA
>seq2
TTTTTTTT
>seq3
CCCCCCCC
>seq4
GGGGGGGG
```

What I want to get is to print every line `( except the lines start with > )` against the other line - desired output should be:

```
AAAAAAAA
TTTTTTTT

AAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCC

AAAAAAAA
GGGGGGGG

TTTTTTTT
CCCCCCCC

TTTTTTTT
GGGGGGGG

CCCCCCCC
GGGGGGGG
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith('>'):
            print(line)
```

You have to read line by line of your file, and test the first character.

Comment: no exactly - I want to print each line against the other every other line - as I have pasted the desire output

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, I will try again

Comment: thank you very much :)